# Algorithm calculate maximum possible sum of expenditure when only spending interest of that year?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

My title may be a bit vague, but I tried to make it as clear as possible. I'll explain what I mean below:

I want to create a dynamic programming algorithm that can calculate the maximum amount you can spend, when the only money you *can* spend each year, is the interest that you get from the bank. So that means that if someone's starting capital is $35,000 for example, that person can only spend a maximum amount of $3500 with an interest rate of 10%.

I have thought of the following:

Interest `i(t)` or basically the amount you can spend, and in the above example this is 3500.

Expenditure `e(t)`, so the amount you spent that year, so this could be anything below 3500, as an example I'll use 1000.

Interest rate `r`, which speaks for itself.

The formula: `i(t + 1) = i(t) + r * (i(t) - e(t))`, which means, the amount you can spend in the next year, is the interest you got this year plus the interest rate times whatever is left after your expenditure.

What I want to calculate is, for example, the maximum sum of expenditure over a period of 10 years, where the expenditure of a certain year is always below the received interest. I have no idea how to do this, and not a clue where to start.

Comment: Wouldn't the maximum expenditure be exactly waiting for the 10 years to end and then spending all the accumulated interest?

Comment: No, because every year the maximum you are allowed to spend is the interest you get from the previous year. So going from year 9 to year 10, the interest you get would roughly be 8300, which isn't the maximum amount you can spend given the constraints.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. :)

Comment: Your question seems to fix the interest calculation rate as annually.  Is that something you definitely want?  Keeping in mind some banks calculate interest on a different schedule that this, the formula could become more complicated.  Just to highlight this, consider that 1% interest every 6 months will pay more (at 2.01% annual cumulative) than 2% calculated at the end of every year.

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the interest annually.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's reform your question. You have a vector E=(e_1, e_2, ..., e_n).
You want to maximize the dot product <(1,1,...,1);(E)> with two conditions.

(1) e_t >= 0 for every t.
(2) e_t <= i_t for every t.

Since right part pf every condition in (2) can be expanded into linear combination of e_t, i_0 and r (you gave a recursive formula), all conditions can be together written as

(2') e_t <=  sum[j=0..n] A_tj e_j, or
(2'') c_t <= sum[j=0..n] B_tj e_j, where B_tj and c_t are some fixed ratios, therefore an n*n sized matrix and n sized vector.

So, now you have a classical [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. I won't describe all the technics of solving those here, because there is a lot of them, and your case is the canonical one.

---

UPD Explicit expansion of constraints via your formula
i(t+1) = (1 + r)i(t) - e(t).
e(0) <= i(0)
e(1) <= i(1) = i(0) (1 + r) - e(0)
e(2) <= i(2) = i(1) (1 + r) - e(1) = (i(0) (1 + r) - e(0)) (1 + r) - e(1) =
i(0) (1 + r)^2 - e(0) (1 + r) - e(1)

It can be proven via induction, but it's also seen that
e(t) <= i(0) (1 + r)^t - e(0) (1 + r)^(t - 1) -
e(1) (1 + r)^(t - 2) - ... - e(t - 2) (1 + r) - e(t - 1)

Reforming that,
e(t) + sum[j=t-1..0] (1 + r)^(t - 1 - j) e(j) <= i(0) (1 + r)^t
So, we have a square matrix:

- B_tj = (1 + r)^(t - 1 - j) for j = 0..t-1,
- B_tt = 1
- B_tj = 0 for j > t

Now your constraints are of form sum[j=0..n] B_tj e(j) <= c_t
(obviously, c_t = i(0) (1 + r)^t)
which is canonical form for LP constraints.

Comment: I realised I could use linear programming to solve this (I've used it before to write a program that creates the best Fantasy Football team), but I have to create a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: @user5368737 You could try to adapt some [existing approach](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69901681), but seems that it could be really complicated

Comment: @user5368737 Also, maybe you could modify knapsack problem dynamic solution making it multidimensional, where each axis would correspond to each linear constraint.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "where each axis would correspond to each linear constraint"?

Comment: @user5368737 In traditional dynamic for knapsack, you have axis X which is given items, and axis Y which is constraint of form sum k_j x_j <= W (W is knapsack size). Calculating table cell with item x_t you move along axis Y at step equal to k_t (weight). Now, in your problem you'll have a hypercube instead of a table, and at item x_t you will move along all axis Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n with corresponding steps (ratios from constraints).

Comment: @user5368737 Note that you won't be able to do it for many years, because even for n=10 it seems that you'll need about 10^9 memory. Or maybe there's some smart way to avoid this, but I'm too lazy to think now.

Comment: @user5368737 Also, you could try consider continuous case with infinitely frequent recapitalisation and apply calculus of variation to maximize integral of e(t), and then somehow deduce approximation for the discrete case. I tried a little, I couldn't. But maybe I didn't try enough.

Comment: I think I will try to think about it more tomorrow, but I don't feel like I'm any closer to understanding how to solve this problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm going to use linear programming to solve it, how would you recommend starting off?

Comment: @user5368737 You mean which algorithm? I'm not strong in that field, the only one I ever used for myself, not for educational purposes, was simplex algorithm; it seemed alright.

Comment: I mean like what formulas / constraints. I don't understand how to maximise e(t) using linear programming, because I don't understand how the constraints would work with t changing from 0 to 20.

Comment: @user5368737 I added part about how to unfold recursion in conditions to the answer.